# LayoutBuilder stops redrawing when surpassing width 900

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have implemented the system from the Flutter adaptive Layout Homepage:

```
class FormFactor {
 static double desktop = 900;
 static double tablet = 600;
 static double handset = 300;
}

enum ScreenType { Desktop, Tablet, Handset, Watch }

ScreenType getFormFactor(BuildContext context) {
  // Use .shortestSide to detect device type regardless of orientation
  double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  log("devicewidth: " + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString());
  if (deviceWidth > FormFactor.desktop) {
    log("Screensize: Desktop");
    return ScreenType.Desktop;
  }
  if (deviceWidth > FormFactor.tablet) {
    log("Screensize: Tablet");
    return ScreenType.Tablet;
  }
  if (deviceWidth > FormFactor.handset) {
    log("Screensize: Handset");
    return ScreenType.Handset;
  }
  return ScreenType.Watch;
}
```

I also have the following Layout Builder in my Widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        log("Width: " + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString() + ", \n Height: " + MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString() + ", \n Type: " + getFormFactor(context).toString(), name: "Dashboard.build()");
        log("Constrainwidth: " + constraints.maxWidth.toString());
        //Desktop
        if (constraints.maxWidth >= FormFactor.desktop) {
          //log("launching Desktop Dashboard", name: "Dashboard.build()");
          return _dashboardDesktop(context);
        }
        //Tablet
        if (constraints.maxWidth > FormFactor.tablet) {
          //log("launching Tablet Dashboard", name: "Dashboard.build()");
          return _dashboardTablet(context);
        }
        //Handset
        if (constraints.maxWidth > FormFactor.handset) {
          //log("launching Handheld Dashboard", name: "Dashboard.build()");
          return _dashboardHandheld(context);
        }
        //Watch or sth else, defaultreturn
        log("falling back to default layout", name: "Dashboard.build()");
        return _dashboardHandheld(context);
      },
    );
  }
```

When I now launch a browser window to check if the Builder works correctly, the output stops working when approaching and sometimes exactly at 900 in height and width values which should not happen as I am trying to develop a webapp. I copied the code so you can play around with dragging the browserwindow.

Why is that?

Edit: I added an example of my Output. It just cuts off after 900 regardless of the Desktop form factor value:

[image]

Comment: it's working here, can you try clean and rebuild

Comment: I selected ``Chrome(web-javascript)``  as my platform and executed ``flutter clean`` and then I started the Project again. I still have this issue. This gets called directly from my main method so I am quite confused. https://imgur.com/a/ClicWKZ

Comment: I found the issue: I wanted to render the desktop without a bottomnavigationbar so I deactivated the layoutbuilder in the scaffold with: ``body: (getFormFactor(context) != ScreenType.Desktop) ? _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex) : Container(),``. Thanks for rechecking, that led me to my issue.